# Java compiler under Eclipse/Ant defaults to %JAVA_HOME%?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac

I recently encountered a build environment behavior that I need to better understand:

Overview of my freshly installed workstation:

1. Installed jdk1.**6**.0_45, then jdk1.**7**.0_80, then jdk1.**8**.0_131.
2. %JAVA_HOME% is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\`
3. Installed Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2)
4. I then manually (by way of unzipping) added to `C:\Program Files\Java` the following: jdk1.**7**.0_45, jre1.**7**.0_76, jre1.**7**.0_79.
5. Checked out a legacy Ant-based project, designed to run under JRE7 only.

My Eclipse's `Window > Preferences > Java  > Installed JREs` now looks:

[image]

Execution environments are [standard](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments#Standard_Execution_Environments) (i.e. I have not added any):

[image]

Now, when I right-click the project's `build.xml` and run that Ant Build... I can see that an execution environment that uses `jre7` (jdk1.**7**.0_80) as its default, is selected:

[image]

So, when I click Apply, then Run, it will use a Java **7** compiler, right?

Wrong. For some strange reason, all `.class` files generated by this build have a [major_version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) of Java 8!

I solved this problem by brute-forcing Ant to use Javac 1.7, via build.xml:

```
<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7"/> 
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.7"/>
```

My question is: **Why** would a build in Eclipse running under JDK8 default to JRE8 *despite Execution Environment set to JDK7*?

IOW, is this a documented feature? If so, where can I learn more about this?

---

**Update:**

Thanks to the answer below, I tried to verify the role of %JAVA_HOME% in Ant's execution. Externally changing my workstation's %JAVA_HOME% system variable would be defeating the purpose of my setup, so I tried changing [%JAVACMD%](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) only. That didn't help. So, I echoed relevant env vars in my `build.xml`:

```
<target name="jdk_version_validation">
    <echo message="Java Version: ${java.version}" />
    <echo message="Java home: ${java.home}" />
    <echo message="JAVA_HOME: ${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
    <echo message="JAVACMD: ${env.JAVACMD}" />
</target>
```

and this is what I got:

```
jdk_version_validation:
     [echo] Java Version: 1.7.0_80
     [echo] Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
     [echo] JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\
     [echo] JAVACMD: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin
```

Without the brute-force property overriding described above, this still produces Java 8 class files. Amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of those things you list appear to be JREs (which don't contain a `javac` compiler). So Ant is probably falling back on using the 1.8 JDK listed in JAVA_HOME.

You could try using the JavaSE-1.7 Execution Evironment and actually select the one JDK you have as the default in the 'Compatible JREs' list.

Comment: Excellent points. I actually tried the JavaSE-1.7 Execution Environment and it worked as you suggested but... I must point out that while jre1.7.0_76 and jre1.7.0_79 are pure JREs (and don't contain a `javac` compiler),  jdk1.7.0_45 and jre7 (jdk1.8.0_131) are JDKs, so I am confused: Why didn't Ant fall back to one of these? If the order in which they are listed also determines the order in which Ant searches for [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html), then  jdk1.7.0_45 is listed there first and should be taken. But Ant still chose the one-before-last in the list. Still unsure

Comment: I think that the following line in Ant's [Javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) documentation may reveal that I simply encountered a peculiar behavior that is specific to Ant:  *The fork attribute overrides the build.compiler property or compiler attribute setting and expects a JDK1.1 or higher to be set in JAVA_HOME*.

Comment: Ant doesn't know anything about the Installed JREs list - all it knows about is the actual JRE Eclipse uses to run it and the JAVA_HOME

Comment: OK, so if everything in Eclipse is set to JRE & JDK **7** (including `Preferences > java > Compiler > JDK Compliance`: 1.7) but the build still uses the JDK8 compiler, then this must be attributed to JAVA_HOME, right?

Comment: Again, Ant doesn't know anything about the Eclipse compiler compliance settings - they are only used by the internal 'ecj' compiler. So yes it looks like it is using JAVA_HOME.